# How to generate a string with user specifying the length

Tags: python

new to python, hope someone can help me.
say here is a string

```
string = "LLLLL"
```

however, I want to generate a string with length "n", where n is specified by user, for exmaple, when user set n=2,then

```
string = "LL"
```

when user set n=10, then

```
string = "LLLLLLLLLL"
```

how can I do this? Thank you in advance.

Moreover, I also want to generate a list like the following, of course, user specify "n", if n=7, then

```
rowname = ["c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7"]
```

how to make this? Thank you very very much.

Comment: For future, you really should not alter your question like that (or ask two totally separate questions in one post).  Instead, you should ask one specific question per topic you want help on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `*` to multiple the string by `n` (which must be an integer):

```
>>> n = 10
>>> 'L' * n
'LLLLLLLLLL'
>>> n = int(raw_input(':'))
:2
>>> 'L' * n
'LL'
>>>
```

Note that if you are on Python 3.x, you will need to replace `raw_input` with `input`.

---

**Edit:**

For your second question, use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> n = int(raw_input(':'))
:7
>>> ["c{}".format(x) for x in xrange(1, n+1)]
['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7']
>>>
```

If you are on Python 3.x, you will need to replace `xrange` with `range`.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply `'L'` by `n`:

```
>>> 'L' * 10
'LLLLLLLLLL'
```

Other sequence types like list, tuple, .. also support `*` operation:

```
>>> ['a', 'b'] * 3
['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
>>> bytearray([1,2,3]) * 2
bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03\x01\x02\x03')
```